# Convert RGB array to 2D RGB array for marker color (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a rgb image:

```
# Random RGB
rgb = np.random.randint(255, size=(900,800,3),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('RGB',rgb)
```

To change the marker color in matlibplot, a 2-D array is needed in which the rows are RGB.

My question is:
How can I reshape the 3D RGB array to change the marker color in a scatter plot?

```
# Load libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import 
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colors
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Random RGB
rgb = np.random.randint(255, size=(900,800,3),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('RGB',rgb)

# Convert to LAB space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)

# Split channels
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

# Convert 2D to 1D vector
a1d = a.flat
b1d = b.flat
# Plot 2D scatter plot for 'a' and 'b'
plt.scatter(a, b, rgb)
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('b')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I receive the following error message:

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 1200 elements, which is not acceptable
>   for use with 'x' with size 1920000, 'y' with size 1920000.

Comment: That's a numpy question, right? `array.flatten()`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. As far as I know, the 2D array should look more like:
[ [intensity value], [R, G, B] ]

in order to change the marker color in a scatter plot.

Comment: `array.reshape(900*800, 3)`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. What I need is a 2D array with 3 columns (R, G, B). Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Yes, `array.reshape(900*800, 3)` gives you a 2D array with three columns. What exactly did not work? (You can [edit] the question to show the problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my post. I hope this makes it clearer, The error message I receive is:
ValueError: 'c' argument has 1200 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 1920000, 'y' with size 1920000.